# Processing close proximity from DataFrame of location updates

Tags: python, data-analysis

I have a dataset of 8 million location updates from simulated routes in a city. The goal is to process this data into contact pairs (detect when people come within 5-10 meters of each other or so). Clusters of more than two people get processed as multiple contact pairs rather than a cluster.

Currently, I'm processing this data by iterating each row of the DataFrame, selecting rows within 5 seconds in either direction of the current iteration, then filtering by distance (`lat`, `lon`) to create the contact pairs.

With 100 vehicles and 24 hours worth of trip data, it takes a few minutes. However, with 10,000 vehicles and 24 hours worth, it's going to take a while to process those contact pairs. My experience in data analysis is NOT extensive whatsoever, so there could be features in pandas I could be missing.

The question is: Is there a more efficient method of generating the contact pairs from the data set?

Edit:
Example data:

```
user_id latitude    longitude   timestamp
4   -86.76699898    36.14179965 1563122927
42  -86.84836186    36.13302701 1563122928
4   -86.76765441    36.14202568 1563122928
42  -86.84805938    36.13306839 1563122929
4   -86.76782552    36.14190853 1563122929
42  -86.84780798    36.13329173 1563122930
4   -86.76785824    36.14148247 1563122930
42  -86.84790658    36.13327074 1563122931
4   -86.76795649    36.14155413 1563122931
1   -86.7829898     36.15960143 1563122931
1   -86.7832536     36.15935017 1563122932
42  -86.84788142    36.13325828 1563122932
4   -86.76810408    36.14155496 1563122932
1   -86.78284727    36.15862057 1563122933
42  -86.84773872    36.13323066 1563122933
4   -86.7680553     36.14149141 1563122933
```

Comment: Please provide easily reproducible DataFrame filled with data, so we can get an Idea

Comment: Example data added (not very diverse considering there's 8 million other rows)